# Edit-Reading xlsx file in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xlsx

I want to read xlsx file but what i want is just to read first three records because as you know if i read all the records, the browser will crash. I need your help to find a way to just read first three records (rows)

P.S: I don't want to save data in memory while parsing xlsx file

i am using this right now :

```
fileChange(event) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file: File = fileList[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => {
        const arrayBuffer = reader.result,
          data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
          arr = new Array();
        for (let i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i) {
          arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        }

        const bstr = arr.join("");

        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
        const firstSheetName: string = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
        this.setXlsxData(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  }

  setXlsxData(data: Array<any>) {
    this.headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
    this.xlsxData = data;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: yes check the code above

Answer (score 1):

try this library. I have written & read some xlsx files, it works smoothly.
(Apologies, I couldnt write this in comment, can't comment)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Havent tried it on my local machine, but I looked at the XLSX library code:

export function readFile(filename: string, opts?: ParsingOptions): WorkBook;

In opts, you can pass : "sheetRows" (which should limit the number of rows to be read)

Comment: i don't want to save data in memory while parsing

Comment: And this question is good. Dont know why someone has downvoted it. I will try to have your requirement implemented on my local machine, and will then write the code here. Meanwhile, you can have a look at the xlsx code. It is pretty descriptive.

Comment: @Justin, Yes, you wont need to save the whole data while parsing, But the first three rows will obviously be saved while reading. Thats why, sheetRows param is there in the function. Again, have to try this to be 100% sure.